# Remove all markers from mapbox map or reinitialize map

Tags: dictionary, line, mapbox, markers

I am using below code to add markers to mapbox map.

```
var marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude],
                        {
                            icon: L.divIcon({
                                html: 'myhtml',
                                iconSize: [40, 40]
                            })
                        });
marker.addto(map);
```

I have added markers using for loop using above code.  Now I want to remove marker to refresh the map.  Is there any was I can remove all markers and polylines from map.  Or if there is any way I can reload the mapbox map.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [map.removeLayer(marker);](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer) to remove the marker (an ILayer object).

Also, addto(map) should be addTo ;)